# Cannot load saved model using torch.load method

Tags: python, torch

I have the problem with loading saved model by torch.load method. Instead of expected serialization I receive string object. Below is my code:

```
class UnknownFuncRLNet(torch.nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, input_dim, output_dim):
    super().__init__()
    self.input_dim = input_dim
    self.output_dim = output_dim

    self.online = torch.nn.Sequential( #!
      torch.nn.Linear(input_dim, 128),
      torch.nn.ReLU(),
      torch.nn.Linear(128, 64),
      torch.nn.ReLU(),
      torch.nn.Linear(64, output_dim)
    )
  def forward(self, input, model):
    return self.online(input.float())


net = UnknownFuncRLNet(2, 1).float()

torch.save(
      dict(model=net.state_dict(), exploration_rate=1),
      '1.chkpt',
    )

net_dict, exploration_rate = torch.load('1.chkpt')
print(type(net_dict))
```

Please explain what are wrong...

Answer (score 0):

The PyTorch recommended way:

To save your model in the current directory with **1.chkpot** name.

```
torch.save(net.state_dict(), '1.chkpt')
```

To load your model from the current directory.

```
net.load_state_dict(torch.load('1.chkpt'))
```

In case you want to load your model in another Python script, You need to initialize your model class first.

Comment: Same result. Also I need to serialize extra params - therefore I use dict